# PHP Include, dropdown nav selected issue

Tags: php, include

I have a PHP include for my navigation. And I wanted to make sure the current menu link was displayed so I have a class `current-menu-item`. All works fine except for the drop down links...

Each page has a `<?php $current_page = "pageName"; ?>`

And i have `<li class="<?php if($current_page == 'dev' || 'seo' || 'mobile' || 'social' || 'hosting') echo "current-menu-item";?>">`

On the main `<li>` that would show as selected when you were on any of the sub links... but when i tried this way it showed as selected on every page on my site...

My site is thwebco.com if you need a reference.

Here is the code...

```
<ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
                        <li class="<?php if($current_page == 'home') echo "current-menu-item";?>"><a href="index.php">Home<span class="subheader">Welcome</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if($current_page == 'development' || 'seo' || 'mobile' || 'social' || 'hosting') echo "current-menu-item";?>"><a href="#">Services<span class="subheader">What we offer</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="development.php"><span> Web Design & Development</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="seo.php"><span> Search Engine Optimization </span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="mobile.php"><span> Mobile </span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="social.php"><span> Social Media </span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="hosting.php"><span> Web Hosting & Email </span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#">Our Work <span class="subheader">See our work</span></a>
                        <ul>
                                <li class="<?php if($current_page == 'portfolio') echo "current-menu-item";?>"><a href="portfolio.php"><span>Portfolio </span></a></li>
                                <li class="<?php if($current_page == 'case') echo "current-menu-item";?>"><a href="case.php"><span>Case Studies </span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                        <li class="<?php if($current_page == 'about') echo "current-menu-item";?>"><a href="about.php">About Us<span class="subheader">Who we are</span></a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="<?php if($current_page == 'contact') echo "current-menu-item";?>"><a href="contact.php">Contact<span class="subheader">Get in touch</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if($current_page == 'quote') echo "current-menu-item";?>"><a href="quote.php">Get A Quote<span class="subheader">Let us help</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `if` is incorrect. It evaluates to true if either `$current_page=='dev'` or `seo`, and non-empty strings always evaluate to true.

It should be:

```
<?php if ($current_page == 'dev' || $current_page == 'seo' || $current_page == 'mobile' || $current_page == 'social' || $current_page == 'hosting') echo "current-menu-item"; ?>
```

Or even simpler:

```
<?php if (in_array($current_page, array('dev', 'seo', 'mobile', 'social', 'hosting')) echo "current-menu-item"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This if statement:

```
if($current_page == 'development' || 'seo' || 'mobile' || 'social' || 'hosting')
```

Isn't necessary INVALID as such, but you are using it wrong. The `||` means OR, so it essectially splits your condition. **This is how your current condition is being processed:**

```
if(
    $current_page == 'development' ||
    'seo' == true; ||
    'mobile' == true; ||
    'social' == true; ||
    'hosting' == true;
)
```

So, of course, due to seo, mobile, social and hosting not equalling to false it is **always** true.

The best way to carry out what you are trying to do is to create an array with the acceptable values and then check the value against that, using [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), like so:

```
$pages = Array("development","seo","mobile","social","hosting");
if(in_array($current_page,$pages);
```